# BASH If Command Not Found

Tags: bash

I have a slight problem with my BASH script that I do not know the cause.

Please take a look at this simple script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Given two integers X and Y. find their sum, difference, product, and quotient

# Constraints
# -100 <= X,Y <= 100
# Y != 0

# Output format 
# Four lines containing the sum (X+Y), difference (X-Y), product (X x Y), and the quotient (X // Y) respectively.
# (While computing the quotient print only the integer part)

# Read data
echo "Please input for x and y!"
read x
read y

declare -i MIN=-100
declare -i MAX=100


# Checks if the valued read is in the constraints
if [ $x -gt $MAX ] || [ $x -lt $MIN ];
then
    echo "Error!"
    exit 1;
elif [ $y -gt $MAX ] || [$y -lt $MIN ] || [$y -eq 0];
then
    echo "Error"
    exit 1;
else
    for operator in {"+","-","*","/",}; do echo "$x $operator $y" | bc; done
fi
```

The output of the script above is as follow.

```
Please input for x and y!
1
2
worldOfNumbers.sh: line 26: [2: command not found
worldOfNumbers.sh: line 26: [2: command not found
3
-1
2
0
```

As you can see, there is this `[2: command not found`. I believe there is something wrong with my syntax however I feel like I have typed the right one.

p.s. I use Oh My ZSH to run the program. I've also tried running in VS Code however the same thing arise.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Your `if` would be simpler written as i.e. `elif ((y>MAX||y<MIN||y==0))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put your code through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net), you'll see that it is due to the lack of spaces between your variable and your bracket. Bash is a space oriented language, and `[` and `]` are commands just like `echo` or `printf`.

Change

```bash
elif [ $y -gt $MAX ] || [$y -lt $MIN ] || [$y -eq 0];
```

to

```bash
elif [ $y -gt $MAX ] || [ $y -lt $MIN ] || [ $y -eq 0 ];
                         ^                  ^        ^
```

Arrows added to show where spaces were added.

You can see that `[` is a command if you run this at your bash prompt:

```
$ which [
[: shell built-in command
```

Because you do not have a space between `[` and `2`, bash assumes that you are trying to run a command called `[2` and that command does not exist, as seen by your error message.

Answer (score -1):

I seemed to fix it. Here is the code.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Given two integers X and Y. find their sum, difference, product, and quotient

# Constraints
# -100 <= X,Y <= 100
# Y != 0

# Output format 
# Four lines containing the sum (X+Y), difference (X-Y), product (X x Y), and the quotient (X // Y) respectively.
# (While computing the quotient print only the integer part)

# Read data
echo "Please input for x and y!"
read x
read y

declare -i MIN=-100
declare -i MAX=100


# Checks if the valued read is in the constraints
if [ "$x" -gt $MAX ] || [ "$x" -lt $MIN ]
then
    echo "Error!"
    exit 1
elif [ "$y" -gt $MAX ] || [ "$y" -lt $MIN ] || [ "$y" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Error"
    exit 1
else
    for operator in {"+","-","*","/",}; do echo "$x $operator $y" | bc; done
fi
```

There should be a space inside the `[ expression ]`. Pretty interesting!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).